# Can anyone suggests some basic readings for video processing?

Tags: video-processing

Actually, I am new to this field and would like to work on a project in Video processing. I have a little background in Image processing but would like to study further in video processing. So, If anyone could suggest some readings as pre-requisites for video processing.

Comment: [Computer vision algorithms and applications](http://szeliski.org/Book/) is a fine place to start.  It is a big field and this is a nice free survey.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Video Tracking: Theory and Practice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470749644)  as comprehensive overview of what have been done in this area for last 15 years. Also, [3D Computer Vision: Efficient Methods and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642017312) for quick understanding useful algorithms.

This books will be a good start, but when you have enough knowledge, you should start looking into research papers, because information there is more updated than in books.